# WPF data binding for textbox not showing in designer when properties are given values in the VM constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am setting the default values for binding. I am setting the values for such properties in the ViewModel class constructor.

#### Here is the ViewModel file code snippets-

```cs
private Contacts contacts;

public Contacts Contacts
{
    get { return contacts; }
    set
    {
        contacts = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Contacts");
    }
}
```

#### constructor-

```cs
public MainWindowVM()
{
    Contacts = new Contacts
    {
        Contact = "Import/Paste Contacts here"
    };

    Import = new Import(this);
    Send = new Send(this);
}
```

#### Here are the Xaml File snippets-

```xml
<Window x:Class="WhatsAppBulkSender_WPF.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WhatsAppBulkSender_WPF.View"
        xmlns:vm ="clr-namespace:WhatsAppBulkSender_WPF.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="#E9E9E9"        
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" MinHeight="450" MinWidth="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainWindowVM x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>

----

    <TextBox x:Name="ContactsTextBox"
            DataContext="{Binding Contacts}"
            Text="{Binding Contact, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            Style="{StaticResource txtBoxStyle}"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Grid.RowSpan="5"/>
```

Issue- The binding works fine and I am able too see changes after the constructor. But the value I have set in the constructor is not shown in the designer or at run time.

#### Screenshot

(Image Showing that The said values are not displayed in designer / xaml)

[image: Image Showing that The said values are not displayed in designer / xaml]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In model class I had members. I was trying to change the value odf thos members from outside the class with getters and setters, when in the first place I didn't declare those variables as a propery.

So, after declaring them as properties things started to work.

Little mistakes can cause you so much trouble sometimes.

Comment: Good for you on a self-answer resolution -- sincerely